# Unique numbering of unsorted sets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, vlookup, countif

Is there a way to make this

```
          ---A---
            John
            John 
            Tim
            steve
            John
          -------
```

into this:

```
        -----A--------B------
           John       1
           John       1
           Tim        2
           Steve      3
           John       1
        ---------------------
```

Have a large data file with duplicate names, and would like to number them in the way mentioned in order to use them in another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A2,A2)=1,MAX(B$1:B1)+1,VLOOKUP(A2,A$1:B1,2,0))
```

in B2 copied down, with labels or blanks in Row1.

Comment: @pnuts So the other day when I used this, it worked perfectly and did exactly what I needed. Today on the other hand, I'm getting the circular reference error, and I can't figure out why. I'm using it in the same was as the other day when I tried this and it worked.

Comment: @pnuts if I get rid of the formula, then the error message no longer pops up. I'm placing the formula in cell B2, and the Trace Precedents shows and error coming from A1, A2, and B1.